# linq using a property that is comprised of multiple properties

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF6 and I wondered if there's an option to use a property that is comprised of multiple other props like so:

```
class Student{
   public int age;
   public string name;
   public int class;
   public string ComplexProp {
      get { return name + age; }
   }
   
} 

students.Where(x => x.class = 4 && x.ComplexProp == "myname5")
```

name, age, class are in the DB. ComplexProp is not. I saw other questions that were similar but a little different and I would like to know how to do it and if it isnt possible what are other alternatives I can use.

maybe its possible to "save" a query `x => x.name + x.age` and use later?

Comment: Normally a LINQ to DB query is translated to the query language (usually SQL) and sent to the database engine to process. The LINQ driver has no way to know how to translate an arbitrary C# method into SQL. You would need a computed column in your table on the SQL side, or use something like [LINQKit](https://www.linqpad.net/) to create a `Expression<Func<>>` that LINQKit could expand inline.

Comment: There are several ways: https://github.com/StefH/Linq.PropertyTranslator.Core
https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/